# Javascript - Create element select from input

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning using the events via "nodes" system. But I always have problems with select and options item. The code is good, it works on my local dev. Unfortunately, I had some bugs in JsFiddle =(

**Here is the situation.**

We have an input, when I type (3 for exemple) and click to "add", I have two inputs (name + surname) that appears for 3 persons in the div "childrenContainer".

**Here is the HTML**

```
<h1>Book</h1>
    <label for="nbEnfants">Number : </label>
    <input type="text" id="nbEnfants">
    <button id="addChildren">Add</button>
    <div id="childrenContainer">
```

**Here is the Javascript**

```
    document.getElementById("addChildren").addEventListener('click',
    function(){
        var nbEnfants = document.getElementById("nbEnfants").value;
        var childrenContainer = document.getElementById("childrenContainer");

        for(var i=0; i<nbEnfants; i++){

            //First added Input
            childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name : " + (i+1) + " "));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            childrenContainer.appendChild(input);
            input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

            //Second input
            childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Surname : " + (i+1) + " "));
            var input2 = document.createElement("input");
            childrenContainer.appendChild(input2);
            input2.setAttribute('type', 'text');

            childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        } 
    }
);
```

This code is good, but I need to add a drop down (select options) for the age of children (1 to 12). Adding inputs is good for me, but adding a select is a little difficult, because I need another loop into this one for adding the age for each children.

**I wrote a little idea if it helps you**

```
for(var i = 0; i<12; i++){
                    var select = document.createElement("select");
                    select.setAttribute("name", "selectChildren");
                    select.setAttribute("id", "selectChildren");
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.setAttribute("value", "value");
                    option.innerHTML = i;
                    select.appendChild(option);
                    childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                }
```

But I don't know how to add a entire drop down after my click event and for each children with his inputs.

I can give you more details if you need help =)

I need explanations if you have a solution, not only the solution, because I will not learn like this =D

Thank you for taking time on my issue =)

Comment: Do you want one select list added for each pair of name/Surname inputs? something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8pro16z/1/)?

Comment: Yes ! Exactly like this ! Can you wait 2 minutes the time I read the code ? I'm very curios, I passed two days to find a solution XD

Comment: It's a stupid question but I don't understand the parameters of setAttributs of the select. Those are not the same parameters than my inputs in terms of order. Could you explain ?

Comment: See the updated explanation in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a different iterator for adding options to the select list**

Since `i` is already used to add each set of inputs, use another variable (e.g. `var j`) when adding options to the select list.

**Create the select list, then add options, then add the list to the DOM**

When creating a new select list, we want the *id* attribute to be unique (refer to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) as to why it should be unique) - and perhaps the *name* attribute should be unique too, especially the form is being submitted with traditional methods (e.g. regular form submit, not AJAX)

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.setAttribute("name", "selectChildren");
select.setAttribute("id", "selectChildren" + i);
for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.setAttribute("value", j+1);
     option.innerHTML = j + 1;
     select.appendChild(option);
}
childrenContainer.appendChild(select); //Add the select list to the DOM
```

Additionally, you can make the *type* attribute of the Number [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) `number` so it will only allow numbers. If you wanted to only allow a range of integers, you could use a select list for that instead.

```js
 document.getElementById("addChildren").addEventListener('click',
   function() {
     var nbEnfants = document.getElementById("nbEnfants").value;
     var childrenContainer = document.getElementById("childrenContainer");

     for (var i = 0; i < nbEnfants; i++) {

       //First added Input
       childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Name : " + (i + 1) + " "));
       var input = document.createElement("input");
       childrenContainer.appendChild(input);
       input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
       childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

       //Second input
       childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Surname : " + (i + 1) + " "));
       var input2 = document.createElement("input");
       childrenContainer.appendChild(input2);
       input2.setAttribute('type', 'text');

       childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
       childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
       var select = document.createElement("select");
       select.setAttribute("name", "selectChildren");
       select.setAttribute("id", "selectChildren" + i);
       for (var j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.setAttribute("value", "value");
         option.innerHTML = j + 1;
         select.appendChild(option);
       }
       childrenContainer.appendChild(select);
       childrenContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

     }
   }
 );
```

```html
 <h1>Book</h1>
<label for="nbEnfants">Number :</label>
<input type="number" id="nbEnfants">
<button id="addChildren">Add</button>
<div id="childrenContainer">
```

Comment: I understand !! My day is shining with this answer and the MDN documentation !! Thank you for those details =)